# VS Code tasks 2.0 troubles

Tags: task, visual-studio-code

I use:

- VS Code 1.14.1
- Tasks 2.0
- node 6.11.1

My problem is that some tasks are working, and some are not.

Here my **tasks.json** file.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        { // This task work fine.
            "label": "tsc",
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        { // This task work fine.
            "taskName": "css",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "./scss.sh",
            "windows": {
                "command": "./scss.cmd"
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "new"
            }
        },        
        { // This task not work. (See output #1 below)
            "taskName": "npm-install",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "npm install",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
            }
        },
        { // This task not work. (See output #2 below)
            "type": "gulp",
            "task": "clean",
            "problemMatcher": []
        }            
    ]
}
```

**Output #1** - When I try to run npm task with type **shell\npm**, I get the same result:

```
> Executing task: npm install <


Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    access, adduser, bin, bugs, c, cache, completion, config,
    ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, edit, explore, get,
    help, help-search, i, init, install, install-test, it, link,
    list, ln, login, logout, ls, outdated, owner, pack, ping,
    prefix, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root,
    run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,
    stars, start, stop, t, tag, team, test, tst, un, uninstall,
    unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view, whoami

npm <cmd> -h     quick help on <cmd>
npm -l           display full usage info
npm help <term>  search for help on <term>
npm help npm     involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    C:\Users\usr\.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@3.10.10 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
```

**Output #2** - When I try to run gulp task I get next (gulp package installed as global (`npm install gulp -g`),(I have **gulpfile.js** with correct content)):

```
> Executing task: node_modules\.bin\gulp.cmd clean <

clean: node_modules.bingulp.cmd: command not found
```

I can use gulp, npm, node and other tools from cmd as usually, and it's works fine, but not in the VS Code.

Current solution of this thing:

1. Create batch files for each stuff.
2. Create shell task for each batch file (as scss.cmd)
3. Run those tasks.

Yep, it works well, but you need to do too much action for simple tasks.

What can you advise in this regard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem, the problem was in the default terminal application.

By default on **Windows OS** visual studio code **use powershell** as terminal app, in my case, I changed it to the git-bash app and got this problem. After that I changed it back to powershell and all works fine.

I did not bother about why gitbash does not work, it is possible that additional configuration is required in the configuration in the vs code.

Answer (score 0):

This is an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/30634) in VS Code. A `<` gets added at the end of commands, making them fail. There doesn't seem to be a direct fix at the moment.